# If Statements java script

Tags: javascript, colors

I had to create a page with `if` statements and need a way to change the color of my font using `if` statements. Is there a tag I can use like for changing the background color?

#### JavaScript:

```js
document.write("<H1>Some Flow of Control</H1>");
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() > 0.5);
document.write("<P>Signed</P>");

if (random) {
    document.write("<img src='bonw.gif' id='myImg'/>")
} else {
    document.write("<img src='wonb.gif' id='myImg'/>")
}

if (random) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = ("white");
} else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = ("black");
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your current code for setting the background color...

Comment: The problem is `document.write`.

Comment: Why does student exercises still insist on `document.write`? Worst API feature ever!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp

you can check this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's :

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

And not :

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = ("black");
```

There's no ().

See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp)

Comment: Yes, it's !! I didn't knew that.
I just answered referring to the documentation.

Comment: great thanks that worked!! is there a tag like this to use to change the font color because when it loads the black background the writing is still black?

Comment: Yes use `.fontcolor("white");`, [See more here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fontcolor.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove the Brackets from the Color name**

```
if(random){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}else{
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

Comment: great thanks that worked!! is there a tag like this to use to change the font color because when it loads the black background the writing is still black?

Answer (score 0):

Create real elements rather than using `document.write`.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/34ped1pw/)

#### JavaScript:

```
// This function will let you create elements easily.
function createElem(args = {}) {
  var elem = document.createElement(args.tag);
  var elemText = document.createTextNode(args.text);
  elem.appendChild(elemText);
  elem.src = args.src;
  elem.id = args.id;
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
createElem({
  tag: 'h1',
  text: 'Some Flow of Control'
});
createElem({
  tag: 'p',
  text: 'Signed'
});
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() > 0.5);
if (random) {
  createElem({
    tag: 'img',
    src: 'http://s25.postimg.org/e2wx0t4p7/chrome.png',
    id: 'myImg'
  });
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
} else {
  createElem({
    tag: 'img',
    src: 'http://s25.postimg.org/kbo7u96hb/safari_1127142725.png',
    id: 'myImg'
  });
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';  // background color
  document.body.style.color = 'white';  // font color
}
```